# Inverse short time Fourier transform

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

The short time Fourier transform $S: L^2(\mathbb{R})^2 \rightarrow L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$ can be defined as

$$S(g,f)(a,b):=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x) \overline{g(x-a)} e^{-i b x} dx.$$

Now a natural question would be to ask for the inverse:

For any $\gamma \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ with $\langle g,\gamma \rangle \neq 0,$ we have formally an inverse given by

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{2 \pi \langle g,\gamma \rangle } \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} S(g,f)(a, b) e^{ib x}\gamma(x-a) da\  db$$

although this seems to me as a well-defined integral in $a$ (Cauchy-Schwartz), I don't see that the integral over $b$ is well-defined. Thus, I was wondering whether the integral over $b$ makes sense, too. Or whether there are more canonical spaces, such that everything here exists?

Comment: As it is written $S$ is antilinear in $g$. Is perhaps $g$ a parameter?

Comment: @Icv its antilinear, so?

Comment: @lcv notice that $g$ is a fixed function (also called window function) and we only want to invert for $f$. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

If the question is, why does your inversion formula holds, the intuition behind it is given by the following identity

$$
\int db e^{-ib(y-x)} = 2 \pi \delta(x-y) 
$$

which is valid in the sense of distribution. If you plug the above into your equation for $f(x)$ you obtain, indeed,

$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{\langle g,\gamma\rangle} \int da \,\,f(x) \overline{g(x-a)} \gamma(x-a)
$$
and the inversion is proved changing variable of integration. If you want a more formal proof you can use similar arguments as those showing that the (standard) Fourier transform operator ${\cal F}$ is a unitary operator from $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ onto itself. In fact the integral representation of the Fourier operator only holds for functions in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$. This can be extended to an operator in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ using:

$$
({\cal F}f)(k) = \lim_{N\to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-N}^N dx 
\,\, e^{ikx} f(x)
$$